# Enable NIS extensions (rfc2307) on Samba 4 AD after installation

Tags: nis, samba4

I'm testing out our samba 4 migration process and when the initial forest/domain was created, it was created without using `--use-rfc2307`:

```
sudo samba-tool domain provision \
              --domain netdirect \
              --realm=ad.netdirect.ca \
              --function-level=2008_R2
```

Now that it's in place and we have machines joined, what do I need to do to add the unix attributes and NIS maps to an existing samba4 domain so that we can use the rfc2307 features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schema extensions from `ypServ30.ldif` must be added:

```
$ kinit administrator@AD.NETDIRECT.CA
Password for administrator@AD.NETDIRECT.CA

$ sed -e 's/${DOMAINDN}/dc=AD,dc=NETDIRECT,dc=CA/g'  \
      -e 's/${NETBIOSNAME}/NETDIRECT/g'              \
      -e 's/${NISDOMAIN}/NETDIRECT/g'                \
      /usr/share/samba/setup/ypServ30.ldif | ldbmodify -H ldap://ad1.ad.netdirect.ca --option="dsdb:schema update allowed=true" -k yes -i
Modified 55 records successfully
```

Then, add to the `[global]` section of `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes
```

Restart samba (`smbcontrol all reload-config`) and you should be good to go.

*(Thanks to Rowland Penny for the [initial directions](https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2013-November/177087.html))*