# Samba 4 schema extension - restart needed?

Tags: samba, samba4, schema

I'm integrating a custom schema in a Samba 4.2 server. This is working quiet well (using `ldbmodify`) but I wonder if it is necessary to stop the samba service before running `ldbmodify`. The [Samba Wiki](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_AD_Schema_Extenstions) says so, also [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/558091/125634) suggests to run `smbcontrol all reload-config` after running `ldbmodify`. On the other hand on my test systems it worked pretty well without stopping or reloading samba at all. Still I fear that I could corrupt the ldb files.

So my question is basically: Should I

- just do the `ldbmodify`?
- run `ldbmodify`, followed by a `smbcontrol all reload-config`?
- stop samba, run `ldbmodify`, start samba?